# Where is this park located, and what are these trees - London UK

Tags: identification

In a scene from Downton Abbey series 6 two characters go walking in a park with a round pond and a fountain surrounded by specimen trees.
[image: Snapshot - no copyright claimed, quotation for research purposes]

A couple of questions: does anyone recognize the park location (storyline indicates London UK but it might be elsewhere) and what are the pyramidal trees (as in top right of this image)?

There is of course "Round Pond" in London, but I think that pond is much larger and has no fountain as in this picture. I have an idea what the trees are but would be interested in other suggestions.

Comment: The trees look like yew topiary. The series was filmed at many different locations around the UK - I've no idea where that garden is. (It's definitely not the Round Pond in Hyde Park, London).

Comment: Unfortunately,, 'London' covers a very large area and there are many parks, as well as large, private estates with parks/gardens - I live in London, but I don't recognise the place from the image above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the Great Fountain Garden at Hampton Court Palace. Lots of pictures at Google Maps [here](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/uv?hl=en&pb=!1s0x48760b0ebea7cefd%3A0x21ba6898072fe6eb!3m1!7e115!4shttps%3A%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipObrfdTxTSbWBb2M7p1qeJtnUAhkCrnHOOy6yWu%3Dw335-h160-k-no!5sgreat%20fountain%20garden%20hampton%20court%20-%20Google%20Search!15sCAQ&imagekey=!1e10!2sAF1QipObrfdTxTSbWBb2M7p1qeJtnUAhkCrnHOOy6yWu&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYsMqw0vvlAhVzpHEKHSpSAi4QoiowEnoECAwQBg).

The conical trees are yew topiary.

According to https://findthatlocation.com/television-show/downton-abbey/location/1156:

> Hampton Court Palace
>
> East Molesey
>
> Lady Edith and Bertie Pelham discuss Brancaster Castle Episode 5
>
> Lady Edith and Bertie Pelham walk through gardens discussing
> Brancaster Castle. The Great Fountain Garden was used.

Comment: Not London then, Hampton Court is in Surrey, not even a London postcode!

Comment: I've been there and the topiary is amazing due it's age and size.